# Django Scheduled task using Django-q

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

Im trying to run scheduled task using [Django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I followed the docs but its not running

heres my config

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'db_cache_table',
    }
}


Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'DjangORM',
    'workers': 4,
    'timeout': 90,
    'retry': 120,
    'queue_limit': 50,
    'bulk': 10,
    'orm': 'default'

}
```

heres my scheduled task
[image]

Nothin is executing, please help

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems with getting scheduled tasks processed in the first place, but finally found a workflow.

I run django-q on a windows machine, using the django ORM as a broker.
Before talking about the execution routine i came up, lets quickly check out my modules first, starting with ..

#### settings.py:

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    "name": "austrian_energy_monthly",
    "workers": 1,
    "timeout": 10,
    "retry": 20,
    "queue_limit": 50,
    "bulk": 10,
    "orm": "default",
    "ack_failures": True,
    "max_attempts": 1,
    "attempt_count": 0,
}
```

..  and my folder structure:


[image]


As you can see, the folder of my django project is inside the src folder. Further, there's a folder for the app i created for this project, which is simply called "app". Inside the app folder i do have another folder called "cron", which includes the following files and functions related to the scheduling:

#### tasks.py

I do not use the schedule() method provided by the django-q, instead i go for the creating tables directly (see: [django-q official schedule docs](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schedules.html#schedule))

```
from django.utils import timezone
from austrian_energy_monthly.app.cron.func import create_text_file

from django_q.models import Schedule

Schedule.objects.create(
    func="austrian_energy_monthly.app.cron.func.create_text_file",
    kwargs={"content": "Insert this into a text file"},
    hooks="austrian_energy_monthly.app.cron.hooks.print_result",
    name="Text file creation process",
    schedule_type=Schedule.ONCE,
    next_run=timezone.now(),
)
```

Make sure you assign the "right" path to the "func" keyword. Just using "func.create_text_file",didn't work out for me, even though these files are laying in the same folder. Same for the "hooks" keyword.

(**NOTE**: I've set up my project as a development package via setup.py, such that i can call it from everywhere inside my src folder)

#### func.py:

Contains the function called by the schedule table object.

```
def create_text_file(content: str) -> str:
    file = open(f"copy.txt", "w")
    file.write(content)
    file.close()
    return "Created a text file"
```

#### hooks.py:

Contains the function called after the scheduled process finished.

```
def print_result(task):
    print(task.result)
```

---

Let's now see how i managed to get the executions running for with the file examples described above:

1. First i've scheduled the "Text file creation process". Therefore I used "python manage.py shell" and imported the tasks.py module (you probably could schedule everythin via the admin page as well, but i didnt tested this yet):
   [image]

You could now see the scheduled task, with a question mark on the success column in the admin page (tab "Scheduled tasks", as within your picture):

[image]

2. **After** that i opened a new terminal and started the cluster with "python manage.py qcluster", resulting in the following output in the terminal:

[image]

The successful execution can be inspected by looking at "13:22:17 [Q] INFO Processed [ten-virginia-potato-high]", alongside the hook print statement "Created a text file" in the terminal. Further you can check it at the admin page, under the tab "Successful Tasks", where you should see:

[image]

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I could only see the schedules after I did `import app.tasks` from the `python manage.py shell`. This worked. But is there no way to automatically start this when we start the server/qcluster?

Answer (score 0):

Django-q dont support windows. :)

Comment: It does support Windows. Check out this article https://www.valentinog.com/blog/django-q/

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command "python manage.py qcluster"

It will work.
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).